# Flutter text field overlay

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a UI in which, when the user clicks on a text field, it should blur out the other elements in the UI. I was thinking of using a stack with an if condition for when the keyboard is visible but I'm not sure if it will work. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any reference image what you are trying to produce?

Comment: It's there in the question itself...